# What is the distinction between Justification and Salvation? (Roman Catholic view)

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, justification

As a practicing Christian, my only hope is for salvation through Jesus Christ.  I note that scripture addresses salvation; in the teaching of the Roman Catholic Church, the Bible is (among other things) a record of Man's salvation  history.  In Paul's letters, being justified is proclaimed to be of profound importance.

If I am to be saved, must I be justified?  I don't think that the two words mean the same thing.

**What is the distinction between being saved and being justified?**

Even reading well presented papers, [such as this one by D.A. Carson](http://www.etsjets.org/files/JETS-PDFs/40/40-4/40-4-pp581-608_JETS.pdf), leaves me puzzled.

Comment: According to who? The denominations differ greatly over this.

Comment: @curiousdannii Do I need more than three?

Comment: Possibly "greatly" is overstating the size of the differences, but there are [major differences in the order of salvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordo_salutis), as well as big differences [over whether justification is a singular event or a process](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/40267/6071).

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks for the links, I admit to confusion and am hoping that in seeing differing theological takes on it, I may get an "aha!" moment.

Comment: I think it is fairly safe to say (@curiousdannii, please correct me if necessary) that whereas Catholics emphasize that justification _transforms us_ (i.e., makes us truly righteous before God), most Protestants (following Luther) would tend to emphasize the _legal_ aspect of justification (i.e., the fact that God _regards_ us as righteous).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Justification

In the Catholic Church, *justification* (from the Latin *iustus*, righteous; and *facio*, to make) means what God does in order to render people *righteous*. (In theological lingo, *justice* means *righteousness*; a *just* person is *right with God*.) As the *Catechism of the Catholic Church* [CCC] puts it,

> The grace of the Holy Spirit has the power to justify us, that is, to cleanse us from our sins and to communicate to us “the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ” and through Baptism ([No. 1987](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c3a2.htm)).

Justification, therefore, is entirely the work of God (see also the *Decree concerning Justification* of the Council of Trent, [Canon 1](http://www.ewtn.com/library/councils/trent6.htm#2)), although, of course, it requires a free acceptance on the part of the person:

> Justification is at the same time the acceptance of God's righteousness through faith in Jesus Christ. Righteousness (or "justice") here means the rectitude of divine love. With justification, faith, hope, and charity are poured into our hearts, and obedience to the divine will is granted us ([CCC 1991](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c3a2.htm); see also the *Decree concerning Justification* [Canon 4](http://www.ewtn.com/library/councils/trent6.htm#2)).

Justification is the work of *grace*:

> Our justification comes from the grace of God. Grace is favor, the free and undeserved help that God gives us to respond to his call to become children of God, adoptive sons, partakers of the divine nature and of eternal life ([CCC 1996](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c3a2.htm)).

## Salvation

For most Catholic theologians, *salvation* refers to *eternal salvation*, that is, people’s full and definitive union with God. For example, that is the use given in the [*Decree concerning Justification*](http://www.ewtn.com/library/councils/trent6.htm).

*Salvation* does not, therefore, coincide perfectly with *justification*. Justification is absolutely necessary for (eternal) salvation; therefore, justification could be viewed as the *beginning* of salvation. (See [CCC 1992](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c3a2.htm).)

Justification, however, at least while people are here on earth, can never be considered definitive, since people can always *lose* their righteousness by deliberately committing grave sins. (See [Canon 23](http://www.ewtn.com/library/councils/trent6.htm#2) of the *Decree concerning Justification*.)

## TL;DR

To sum up the difference: *justification* means what God does to make people *righteous* and right with Him; *salvation* means the full realization of that justification, when people reach their definitive union with Him.

Comment: You beat me! Hmf. And here I was typing away as fast as I could.

Comment: I think part of my problem has always been the mundane use of justification in English, and the theological definition that you and @Nathaniel (in his answer) have explained in your answers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is related to [my previous answer to another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/40267/12563) which discusses the two concepts briefly in relation to "salvation by works or faith".

*Justification*, according to the Catholic Church, is the grace of the Holy Spirit when it is used "to cleanse us from our sins and to communicate to us 'the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ' and through Baptism." (*Catechism of the Catholic Church* [CCC] paragraph 1987, quoting Romans 3:22) It is the gift given us by God which makes us "dead to sin and living for God in Christ Jesus" (Romans 6:11b, NABRE)

It is this justification which allows us to pass beyond the sinful state we inherit by virtue of being human; which allows us to be cleansed of our original sin, to repent, and be forgiven:

> Moved by grace, man turns toward God and away from sin, thus accepting forgiveness and righteousness from on high. "Justification is not only the remission of sins, but also the sanctification and renewal of the interior man."

(*CCC* paragraph 1989, quoting the Council of Trent)

Justification, then, is **necessary** for salvation, since it is God's gift of grace to us which allows us to live and work in him. But it is not salvation itself. As I explained in the answer I referred to above, God invites and allows human beings to cooperate with him in order to live (and die, and live again) fully in him. It is this fullness of life—in particular, of eternal life with God after death—which is *salvation* itself.

I discussed elsewhere whether or not Catholics believed in the "once saved, always saved" viewpoint espoused by many evangelical Protestants; I concluded that in a sense they did. *Justification* is given in the Sacrament of Baptism at the beginning of Christian life; but Catholics believe that they attain the fullness of *salvation* only at the end of life.

Comment: Thank you, also a good answer.  I had read that other answer and felt ... I almost get it.   That answer got me the link to the join declaration, which I think I'll understand better now that you and @AthanasiusofAlex have provided me with better understanding of the RCC PoV.

Comment: Just a quibble: justification doesn’t just make us “pass beyond Original Sin;” it cleanses us from Original Sin (=the privation of sanctifying grace)—i.e., it _removes_ Original Sin.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex That's really what I meant; but I agree, that's not the best way of saying it. Thanks.

Comment: @MattGutting Good. Now I can give +1 :).